# subtracting timestamps in SQL to provide time by hours

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table of "car trips" with their timestamps,
I appreciate your help with the below query to subtract two timestamps to provide the time it took to finish a trip.

EXAMPLE:

trip started on 2020-10-01 19:00
and ended on 2020-10-02 00:30
the expected result of the query is 5:30 hours

```
select  s.order_time,
    TO_CHAR(s.tripStart,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI') AS START,
    TO_CHAR(s.tripEnd,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI') AS END
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` is Oracle. The MySQL function is `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, yes it is oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the `tripStart` from `tripEnd` to give an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type and then extract the number of hours and minutes:

```sql
SELECT tripStart,
       tripEnd,
       TO_CHAR(
           EXTRACT( DAY  FROM difference ) * 24
         + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM difference ),
         'FM00'
       )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( ABS( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM DIFFERENCE ) ), 'FM00' )
         AS hour_min_duration
FROM   (
  SELECT tripStart,
         tripEnd,
         ( tripEnd - tripStart ) DAY TO SECOND AS difference
  FROM   car_trips
)
```

*(Note: The query above will work for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` data types.)*

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE car_trips ( tripStart, tripEnd ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 19:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-02 00:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 19:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-02 19:59:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 19:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 00:30:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> TRIPSTART           | TRIPEND             | HOUR_MIN_DURATION
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :----------------
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-02 00:30:00 | 05:30            
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-02 19:59:00 | 24:59            
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-01 00:30:00 | -18:30
> ```

---

If you just want to convert your `TIMESTAMP` (or `DATE`) values to an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type then subtract with an explicit conversion to an `INTERVAL`:

```sql
SELECT tripStart,
       tripEnd,
       ( tripEnd - tripStart ) DAY TO SECOND AS difference
FROM   car_trips;
```

*(This won't get your `HH:MI` format but, when converted to a string does show the time components of the difference.)*

Which outputs:

> ```
> TRIPSTART           | TRIPEND             | DIFFERENCE         
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-02 00:30:00 | +00 05:30:00.000000
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-02 19:59:00 | +01 00:59:00.000000
> 2020-10-01 19:00:00 | 2020-10-01 00:30:00 | -00 18:30:00.000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f346e86f5d15b7369239a57dffc187c)*

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **timestamp** conversion instead of **char** conversion with the seconds(**SS**) portion to be added (*at least*) when formatting a **timestamp** value.

Use

```
WITH t(tripStart,tripEnd) AS
(
 SELECT timestamp'2020-10-01 19:00:00' , timestamp'2020-10-02 00:30:00' FROM dual
)
SELECT tripEnd - tripStart AS "Result"
  FROM t;

Result
-------------------
+000000000 05:30:00
```

or

```
WITH t(tripStart,tripEnd) AS
(   
 SELECT to_timestamp('2020-10-01 19:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') , 
        to_timestamp('2020-10-02 00:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual  
)
SELECT tripEnd - tripStart AS "Result" 
  FROM t;   

Result
-------------------
+000000000 05:30:00
```

Comment: thanks Ozhan! but forgive my ignorance, I expect thousands of rows as a result from my query, so what should I replace the example timestamp you provided with ?

Comment: Hi @iAlsunaid , you're welcome. How do you hold your data within the table. What's the data type, and are they all exactly as you stated ?